# Magento 2 How to use header variable in resolver?

Tags: graphql, http-header, magento24, authentication

I have created one graphql extension for customer OTP send and verify for login with OTP in the project's POS app.

There are two requests

- When POS app request OTP with customer_id and pos session_id, it sends OTP to the customer.
- When POS app requests verify OTP with customer_id, OTP, and session_id, it checks the sent OTP with the requested OTP if is correct it returns success.

`SmsGraphQl/Model/Resolver/CustomerOtpSend.php`

```
public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($args['customer_id']) || !isset($args['session_id'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__("Please provide 'customer_id' and 'session_id' first!"));
        }
        $sessionId = $args['session_id'];
        if (!$this->data->validateStaffSession($sessionId)){
            return [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => __("Invalid 'session_id'!")
            ];
        }
        try {
            $customerId = $args['customer_id'];
            $customer = $this->customerRegistry->retrieve($customerId);
            $success = true;
            $message = "OTP send successfully!";
            $this->seeSmsHelper->sendAuthentication($customer);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $success = false;
            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return [
            'success' => $success,
            'message' => $message
        ];
    }
```

`SmsGraphQl/Model/Resolver/CustomerOtpVerify.php`

```
public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($args['customer_id']) || !isset($args['otp']) || !isset($args['session_id'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__("Please provide 'customer_id', 'session_id' and 'otp' first!"));
        }

        $customerId = $args['customer_id'];
        $sessionId = $args['session_id'];
        $otp = $args['otp'];

        if (!$this->_data->validateStaffSession($sessionId)){
            return [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => __("Invalid 'session_id'!")
            ];
        }

        $collection = $this->_mobileCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mobile::STATUS_NOT_VERIFIED)
            ->addFieldToFilter('otp', $otp);

        $mobile = $collection->getFirstItem();
        if ($collection->count() == 0) {
            return [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => ConstantsInterface::OTP_INVALID_MSG
            ];
        }

        $mobile->setStatus(Mobile::STATUS_VERIFIED)->save();

        return [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => __("valid OTP.")
        ];
    }
```

Requirement

> POS is already sent session_id in the header. So in place of the use parameter, we need to use the header variable.

If anyone has used the header variable in Magento 2 graphql then help or provide documentation, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into the core codes but didn't find a Magento way to get the request headers in graphql resolver yet. I will update the answer once I'll have more information. Meanwhile, you can use the below way.

You can get all the request headers using the below function.

```
$getHeaders = apache_request_headers();
$sessionId = $getHeaders['Session-Id'];
```

But it also has some limitations, as I checked ***apache_request_headers()*** function does not return a header which is having underscore in its key. Instead of underscore, you can use the hyphen.

```
key   : session-id
value : custom
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We found a way to validate the header with graphql. We got reference from `vendor/magento/module-store-graph-ql`, `vendor/magento/module-wishlist-graph-ql` and `vendor/magento/module-customer-graph-ql`.

`WebposGraphQl/etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface">
        <attribute code="pos_session" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

`WebposGraphQl/etc/graphql/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\GraphQl\Controller\HttpRequestProcessor">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="requestValidators" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="posSessionIdValidator" xsi:type="object">*\WebposGraphQl\Controller\HttpRequestValidator\PosSessionValidator</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="contextParametersProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="add_pos_session_id_to_context" xsi:type="object">*\WebposGraphQl\Model\Context\AddPosSessionIdToContext</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`WebposGraphQl/Model/Context/AddPosSessionIdToContext.php`

```
<?php
namespace *\WebposGraphQl\Model\Context;

use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextParametersInterface;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextParametersProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use *\WebposGraphQl\Api\Data\ConstantInterface;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
class AddPosSessionIdToContext implements ContextParametersProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    public $context;

    /**
     * AddPosSessionIdToContext constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute(ContextParametersInterface $contextParameters): ContextParametersInterface
    {
        $contextParameters->addExtensionAttribute(
            ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION,
            $this->context->getData(ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER)
        );
        return $contextParameters;
    }
}
```

`WebposGraphQl/Controller/HttpRequestValidator/PosSessionValidator.php`

```
<?php
namespace *\WebposGraphQl\Controller\HttpRequestValidator;

use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
use Magento\Framework\App\HttpRequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\GraphQl\Controller\HttpRequestValidatorInterface;
use *\Webpos\Helper\Data;
use *\WebposGraphQl\Api\Data\ConstantInterface;

class PosSessionValidator implements HttpRequestValidatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $webposHelper;

    /**
     * @var HttpContext
     */
    private $httpContext;

    /**
     * PosSessionValidator constructor.
     *
     * @param Data $webposHelper
     * @param HttpContext $httpContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $webposHelper,
        HttpContext $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->webposHelper = $webposHelper;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the header 'pos-session' value.
     *
     * @param HttpRequestInterface $request
     * @return void
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function validate(HttpRequestInterface $request): void
    {
        $headerValue = $request->getHeader(ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER);

        if (empty($headerValue)) {
            $this->httpContext->setValue(
                ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER,
                null,
                0
            );
        } else {
            $posSessionId = trim($headerValue);
            if ($this->isSessionIdExist($posSessionId)) {
                $this->httpContext->setValue(
                    ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER,
                    $posSessionId,
                    1
                );
            } else {
                $this->httpContext->setValue(
                    ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER,
                    null,
                    0
                );
                throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Requested pos session id %1 is not found', $posSessionId));
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate session id.
     *
     * @param string $posSessionId
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isSessionIdExist(string $posSessionId): bool
    {
        return $this->webposHelper->validateStaffSession($posSessionId);
    }
}
```

`SmsGraphQl/etc/schema.graphqls`

```
type Query {
    sendCustomerOtp (
        customer_id: Int @doc(description: "Customer id.")
    ): SendCustomerOtpOutput @resolver(class: "*\\SmsGraphql\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomerOtpSend")
    @doc(description: "Send the otp to requested customer id.")
    verifyCustomerOtp (
        customer_id: Int @doc(description: "Customer id.")
        otp: String @doc(description: "OTP provided by customer.")
    ): VerifyCustomerOtpOutput @resolver(class: "*\\SmsGraphql\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomerOtpVerify")
    @doc(description: "Verify otp provided by customer.")
}

type SendCustomerOtpOutput @doc(description: "Response the send status.") {
    success: Boolean @doc(description: "Success status.")
    message: String @doc(description: "Send status message.")
}

type VerifyCustomerOtpOutput @doc(description: "Response the verify status.") {
    success: Boolean @doc(description: "Success status.")
    message: String @doc(description: "Send status message.")
}
```

`SmsGraphQl/Model/Resolver/CustomerOtpVerify.php`

```
<?php
namespace *\SmsGraphql\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Vnecoms\Sms\Helper\Data;
use Vnecoms\Sms\Model\ResourceModel\Mobile\Collection;
use Vnecoms\Sms\Model\Mobile;
use *\Sms\Api\ConstantsInterface;
use *\WebposGraphQl\Api\Data\ConstantInterface;

class CustomerOtpVerify implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $_mobileCollection;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_vnecomsHelper;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * CustomerOtpVerify constructor.
     *
     * @param Collection $mobileCollection
     * @param Data $vnecomsHelper
     * @param DateTime $date
     */
    public function __construct(
        Collection $mobileCollection,
        Data $vnecomsHelper,
        DateTime $date
    ) {
        $this->_date = $date;
        $this->_mobileCollection = $mobileCollection;
        $this->_vnecomsHelper = $vnecomsHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Resolve query.
     *
     * @param Field $field
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param ResolveInfo $info
     * @param array|null $value
     * @param array|null $args
     * @return array
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $posSession = $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getPosSession();
        if (isset($posSession[ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER])) {
            if ((bool)$posSession[ConstantInterface::POS_SESSION_HEADER]) {
                if (!isset($args['customer_id']) || !isset($args['otp'])) {
                    throw new GraphQlInputException(__("Please provide 'customer_id' and 'otp' first!"));
                }

                $customerId = $args['customer_id'];
                $otp = $args['otp'];
                $collection = $this->_mobileCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mobile::STATUS_NOT_VERIFIED)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('otp', $otp);

                $mobile = $collection->getFirstItem();
                $otpExpireTime = $this->_vnecomsHelper->getOtpExpiredPeriodTime();
                if ((strtotime($mobile->getOtpCreatedAt()) + $otpExpireTime) < $this->_date->timestamp()) {
                    return [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => ConstantsInterface::OTP_EXPIRED_MSG
                    ];
                }

                if ($collection->count() == 0) {
                    return [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => ConstantsInterface::OTP_INVALID_MSG
                    ];
                }

                $mobile->setStatus(Mobile::STATUS_VERIFIED)->save();
                return [
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => __("valid OTP.")
                ];
            } else {
                throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('The current POS Session is not authorized.'));
            }
        } else {
            throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('Can not find pos session id in header!'));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As i correct understand your question, you can initialize in `__constructor` request `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` and use `getHeader('key', 'default')` method

Comment: Sorry, Can't get the header from the request object.

Comment: indirect Magento uses a request object and passes a specific header value to the resolver.